# cfquery ColdFusion execution

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sequences

Does cfquery execute on every page load?  I ask because I'm getting a sequence number with the query and then using it in a form.  Unfortunatly, the query seems to execute every time the page loads.  I don't want that to happen.  I also tried putting it inside of a cffunction and then calling it out of the onSubmit parameter of of the cfinput box that uses the sequence number, but it still calls the sequence.

Here are examples of the way I've tried to do this:

```
<cfquery name="payment_seq_num" datasource="ORCL">
        select ratner01.payment_id_seq.nextval as seq from dual
    </cfquery>
  <cfset paymentid = payment_seq_num.seq>
```

And

```
<cffunction name="getVetSeq" output="false">
  <cfquery name="vet_seq_num" datasource="ORCL">
        select ratner01.vet_id_seq.nextval as seq from dual
    </cfquery>
  <cfset  vet_form.VET_ID = vet_seq_num.seq>

</cffunction>
```

I get why the first one keeps incrementing...it's in the head and is called everytime.  But why would the second one execute every page load?

Here's how I'm calling it:

```
<cfform action="vet_output.cfm" method="post" format="html" class="cfform" name="vet_form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a Veterinarian to the Databse</legend> 
    <table>
        <tr><cfoutput>
            <td><cfinput type="hidden" name="VET_ID" onsubmit="#getVetSeq()#"></td></cfoutput>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vet First Name:<br/> <cfinput type="text" name="VET_FNAME" maxlength="35"></td>
            <td>Vet Last name: <br/><cfinput type="text" name="VET_LNAME" maxlength="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <td><cfinput type="submit" value="Insert" name="vetSubmit"></td>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
</cfform>
```

So I added this into the output page and removed all related code from the input page, thanks to some suggestions, and it worked... :

```
  <cfquery name="vet_seq_num" datasource="ORCL">
            select ratner01.vet_id_seq.nextval as seq from dual
        </cfquery>
  <cfset FORM.VET_ID = vet_seq_num.seq>
  <cfinsert name="insert_vet" datasource="ORCL" username="XX" password="XX"
    tablename="VET"
    formfields="VET_ID, VET_FNAME, VET_LNAME">
```

Comment: The second one would only execute on every page load if getVetSeq() is being called on every page load. Is that the case?

Comment: So how do you want this called?  Is it supposed to be called once per user? Once per application initialization? Once per day?  The behavior you want will determine how it should be called.

Comment: Why are you getting the VET_ID on the form page? Are you inserting VET_FNAME and VET_LNAME into the database in output.cfm?

Comment: @BarryJordan: Yes, in the output.cfm page using a cfinsert tag.

Comment: @webhound - Then you should generate the ID right before the `cfinsert`, not on the form page. Assuming you have to do this manually that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so every time this page is loaded you will call that function and get a new sequence number.  Because everytime you load the page #getVetSeq()# will be executed by ColdFusion.

I know you put it in onSubmit() but onSubmit() is a JavaScript event, which has no knowledge of ColdFusion. By the time JavaScript sees that code the function has already been called. If you look you'll probably see JS errors because when you click submit you are actually calling a non-existant function. Because your code renders as something like:

```
onsubmit="1234"
```

If you only want it called when the form is submitted then do it in your output.cfm instead of in your form.

If for some reason you need to do it on this page instead of in your processing page, then you'll need to look at doing it as an Ajax call so that it only executes onSubmit().

Comment: @webhound - Though in general, ID's should be created when the values are saved to the database, not before. Otherwise you are just burning id's that may or not be used.

Comment: how do I access a cfinput value and change it in the output form?  Is there a post array, or something like that?  I've tried :    `<cfquery name="vet_seq_num" datasource="ORCL">
      select ratner01.vet_id_seq.nextval as seq from dual
     </cfquery>
   <cfset vet_form.VET_ID = vet_seq_num.seq>`  I've also tried it without the vet_form prefix and also with form.VET_ID.  I get nulls all three ways.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <cfset  vet_form.VET_ID = vet_seq_num.seq>
> ```

Form values submitted via `method="POST"` are available in a system structure named `FORM`. It is always called `FORM`, regardless of the name assigned to your `<form>`. So the correct variable name is:

```
FORM.VET_ID
```

However, it is cleaner not to access the `FORM` scope from within the function. Just have the function generate and return the new ID and leave the rest up to the calling page. That makes the function more modular/resuable. But remember to [`var`](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/8/22/Object-Oriented-Coldfusion--4--The-var-scope) scope all function local variables (for ColdFusion 9+ use the `Local` scope)

```
<!--- Usage --->
<cfset FORM.VET_ID = generateNewVetID()>

<!--- Function --->
<cffunction name="generateNewVetID" output="false" returnType="numeric">
    <cfset var vet_seq_num = "">
    <cfquery name="vet_seq_num" datasource="ORCL">
        SELECT ratner01.vet_id_seq.nextval AS seq 
        FROM   dual
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn vet_seq_num.seq>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Leigh, thanks, I think I was writing what worked as you were adding this.  Saw your comment earlier though, and it helped.

Comment: Welcome. It is really more of a comment than an answer, but comments do not allow for that much code ;)